# How to parse list<String> or String in one variable

Tags: java, jackson

I am working on a JSON Serialisation and i have a scenerio where a field in JSON can be a String/ List of Strings. I am not sure how to serialise such object.

```
@Data
public class NonNullRatio extends Constraint {
    @NonNull private List<String> column;
    @NonNull private Assertion assertion;
}
```

The input JSON Could be -

```
"        \"constraints\": [\n" +
    "          {\n" +
    "            \"type\": \"NonNullRatio\",\n" +
    "            \"column\": [\"transaction_status\", \"user_charge_id\", \"psp_transaction_id\"],\n" +
    "            \"assertion\": {\n" +
    "              \"type\": \"LowerLimit\",\n" +
    "              \"threshold\": 1\n" +
    "            }\n" +
    "          },\n" +
```

OR

```
"        \"constraints\": [\n" +
            "          {\n" +
            "            \"type\": \"NonNullRatio\",\n" +
            "            \"column\": \"ufi\",\n" +
            "            \"assertion\": {\n" +
            "              \"type\": \"LowerLimit\",\n" +
            "              \"threshold\": 1\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "          },\n" +
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell your Jackson to accept String as Array.

You can do this using -

```
@JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
```

Your POJO Should look like -

```
@Data
public class NonNullRatio extends Constraint {
    @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
    @NonNull private List<String> column;
    @NonNull private Assertion assertion;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You could configure Jackson `ObjectMapper` using [this](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY) option to accept single value as array.

```
 new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true)
```

Example -

```
class SomeClass{
    private List<String> values;
    // getter setters
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SomeClass{" +
                "values=" + values +
                '}';
    }
}


public class TestJSON {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
        String jsonString = "{\"values\":\"A\"}";
        System.out.println(objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, SomeClass.class));
        jsonString = "{\"values\":[\"A\",\"B\"]}";
        System.out.println(objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, SomeClass.class));
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
SomeClass{values=[A]}
SomeClass{values=[A, B]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help